# Matching first and last three characters of regex (including overlap)

Tags: regex

I am trying to put together a regex expression that matches a word (only one per line) that starts and ends with the same three characters.

I was able to write a solution for words that are at least 6 characters long (meaning there is no overlap), but I am unsure how to do it for overlapping starts and ends such as "heheh".

This is what I have, nice and simple:
`^(...).*\1$`

I am inclined to believe that this might have something with lookahead and lookbehind but I am not sure.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Right, you will need lookarounds such as in `grep -P '^(?=(...))(?=.*\1$)' file` ([demo](https://ideone.com/RAxGuN))

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, this is enough to be an answer, why not make it one?

Answer (score 3):

You will need [lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) since they are *non-consuming* patterns, i.e. the regex index is not advanced when the lookaround pattern is matched.

For example, you may do this with GNU `grep`:

```
grep -P '^(?=(...)).+\1$' file
grep -P '^(?=(\S{3})).+\1$' file # To avoid counting in spaces
grep -P '^(?=(\w{3})).+\1$' file # Or only allowing letters/digits/underscores
grep -P '^(?=(\p{L}{3})).+\1$' file # Or only allowing letters
```

See the [regex demo](https://ideone.com/14v8wV)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=(...))` - a positive lookahead with a capturing group inside that matches any 3 chars
- `.+` - any 1+ chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `\1` - Group 1 value
- `$` - the end of string.

To extract words, you may use `\w` shorthand (that matches letters, digits and underscores) and word boundaries `\b`:

```
grep -oP '\b(?=(\w{3}))\w+\1\b' file
```

See [another demo](https://ideone.com/S5FFZv).

**Details**

- `\b` - a word boundary (start of word here, because it is followed with word chars)
- `(?=(\w{3}))` - a positive lookahead making sure there are 3 word chars while capturing them into Group 1
- `\w+` - 1+ word chars (not 0 or more because otherwise a 3-char word would be matched)
- `\1` - Group 1 value
- `\b` - end of word here (as it is preceded with word chars).