# First three and last characters match - regex backreferencing

Tags: regex, bash

I am trying to create a regular expression that matches words whose first and last three characters are the same.

Unfortunately, I am using extended regular expressions, so lookarounds are not allowed. I have successfully written a regular expression that matches words that are:

three characters long - "abc"

four characters long - "aaaa"

five characters long - "qrqrq"

I cannot seem to implement the part that should be easiest: matching a word that is six or more characters long like "runrun" or "rawrunraw". My regular expression looks this:

`^(.)((.)|\1|\3|\3)((.)$|\1\1$|\1\3\1$|\5.*\1\3\5$)`

Using the logic I used for words shorter than six characters, I cannot figure out why this won't work. It seems like it should.

Comment: This question is essentially the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61333557/matching-first-and-last-three-characters-of-regex-including-overlap/61334127#61334127) with the additional requirement that lookarounds cannot be used.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work for me.

```
^(...|(.)\2{3}|(.)(.)\3\4\3|(...).*\5)$
```

- `^...$` any three character
- `(.)\2{3}` the same character four times
- `(.)(.)\3\4\3` the pattern ABABA
- `(...).*\5` three characters, anything in between, the same three characters at the end

The test:

```
#!/bin/bash

cat <<EOF | grep -E '^(...|(.)\2{3}|(.)(.)\3\4\3|(...).*\5)$'
abc
aaaa
x--x
qrqrq
-xxx-
runrun
--xx--
rawwetraw
EOF
```